# Populate a property according to another one with SpEL in application.properties

Tags: spring, properties-file, spring-el

Here is the `application.properties` file:

```
myVar=${SOME_VAR:#{null}}
result=myVar is #{myVar != null && myVar.length() > 0 ? '' : 'not'} populated
```

What I am trying to get is if the environment variable `SOME_VAR` is set (and not blank), the property `result` should be `myVar is populated`, otherwise `myVar is not populated`.
The code I put above doesn't work (the line to set `result`), and I have also tried different combinations of #{} and ${}, including wrapping `myVar`, but no success so far.

What is the correct way to do? Thanks.

Comment: Is the answer useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to refer the myVar field directly if your member variable are private. So you should put your condition directly on the property value.

please check below expression as per your requirement.

```
@Value("myVar is #{ '${SOME_VAR}' != null && '${SOME_VAR}'.trim().length() > 0 ? '' : 'not'} populated")
private String result;
```

The #{ } is an expression language feature, while ${ } is a simple property placeholder syntax.

Comment: Thanks for replying, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing

```
result=myVar is #{'${SOME_VAR:#{null}}' != '#{null}' && '${SOME_VAR:#{null}}'.trim().length() > 0 ? '' : 'not'} populated
```